# How to interpret user input as a variable name?

Tags: bash, variables, case, indirection, pacman-package-manager

This one is kind of hard to explain. Consider variables `all`, `first`, `last`, and `some`:

```
a="apple mcintosh"
b="banana plantain"
c="coconut cashew"
all="$a $b $c"
first="$a"
last=$c"
some="$a $c"
```

Here is what I have:

```
echo "What do you want to install?"
echo "all, first, last, or some?"
read userinput
```

Assuming that the user types `all`, his input shall be treated as the name of a variable: I want the next command to be `pacman -S $all` (equivalent to `pacman -S apple mcintosh banana plantain coconut cashew`). Likewise, if the user types both `first` and `last`, the next command has to be `pacman -S $first $last` (which in fact should execute `pacman -S apple mcintosh coconut cashew`).

I used `case/esac` to translate `userinput` into a variable, but I am looking for a more flexible and elegant solution, as this approach doesn't allow more than one input.

```
case $userinput in                                             
  all)   result="$all";;
  first) result="$first";;
  *)     exit;;
esac

pacman -S $result
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you're after is an [indirect variable reference](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Shell-Parameter-Expansion), which has the form `${!var}`:

> **3.5.3 Shell Parameter Expansion**
>
> *[...]* If the first character of *parameter* is an exclamation point (!), a level of variable indirection is introduced. Bash uses the value of the variable formed from the rest of *parameter* as the name of the variable; this variable is then expanded and that value is used in the rest of the substitution, rather than the value of *parameter* itself. This is known as indirect expansion.

For example:

```
$ a="apple mcintosh"
$ b="banana plantain"
$ c="coconut cashew"
$ all="$a $b $c"
$ first="$a"
$ last="$c"
$ some="$a $c"
$ read userinput
all
$ result=${!userinput}
$ echo $result
apple mcintosh banana plantain coconut cashew
```

To expand multiple items, use `read -a` to read words into an array:

```
$ read -a userinput
first last
$ result=$(for x in ${userinput[@]}; do echo ${!x}; done)
$ echo $result
apple mcintosh coconut cashew
```

Comment: Nice answer! I just wrote one that uses `eval` but your approach is much more elegant so i discarded my answer.

Comment: It sure is elegant, but it still fails to handle more than one input. It's nice to finally know how it's called, though.

Answer (score 1):

For reading user input from a list of choices, bash's `select` is what you need. Also, when you start to ask "how do I dynamically build a variable name", think associative arrays instead:

```
a="apple mcintosh"
b="banana plantain"
c="coconut cashew"

declare -A choices
choices[all]="$a $b $c"
choices[first]="$a"
choices[last]="$c"
choices[some]="$a $c"

PS3="What do you want to install? "

select choice in "${!choices[@]}"; do
    if [[ -n $choice ]]; then
        break
    fi
done

echo "you chose: ${choices[$choice]}"
```

---

The above does not handle multiple choices. In that case, then (still using the "choices" array from above):

```
options=$(IFS=,; echo "${!choices[*]}")
read -rp "What do you want to install ($options)? " -a response
values=""
for word in "${response[@]}"; do
    if [[ -n ${choices[$word]} ]]; then
        values+="${choices[$word]} "
    fi
done
echo "you chose: $values"
```

This uses `read`'s `-a` option to read the response into an array. What it looks like:

```
$ bash select.sh 
What do you want to install (some,last,first,all)? first middle last
you chose: apple mcintosh coconut cashew
```